# Trying to understand how they got equation for Vzo

Tags: voltage, diodes, zener

this might seem like an easy question but I'm still new to circuits and I'm trying to understand how they got the equation for voltage.[image]

They have the solution as 6.8=Vzo+5m(20), but when I looked at it I thought It was Vzo=6.8+5m(20) because for the circuit Vzo comes first then comes 6.8v, so why not go in that order?

Answer (score 0):

According to the picture, the 6.8 V is across the series combination of both Zener voltage and the resistor.
[image]

With out further context, I can only go ahead with the image. As per the image, the equations derived are right.

---

It is the representation of Zener diode as a whole. Hence the statement, the Zener diode has 6.8 V across it. When you **split Zener diode into it's equivalent of voltage and a series resistor**, the voltage too gets divided. 
[image]